# Why my scss variable wasn't parsed as expected?

Tags: html, css, sass

This is the output I want to get:

[image]

---

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/t5ewp8ax/

```html
// html
<p class="movie-category">
  <span>Sentimental</span>
  <span>Romantic</span>
  <span>Dramedy</span>
</p>
```

```css
// scss
.movie-category {
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: blue;

  > span:not(:last-child) {
    $distance: 1em;
    $half-distance: $distance / 2;
    margin: 0 $distance 0 0;

    position: relative;
  }
  > span:not(:last-child)::after {
    $size: .2em;
    $half-size: $size / 2;

    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - $half-size);
    left: calc(100% + $half-distance - $half-size);

    display: block;
    width: $size;
    height: $size;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

And it seems the lines:

```
  > span:not(:last-child) {
    $distance: 1em;
    margin: 0 $distance 0 0;
  }
```

was parsed correctly to `margin: 0 1em 0 0;`. But

```css
  > span:not(:last-child)::after {
    left: calc(100% + $half-distance - $half-size);
  }
```

wasn't being parsed to `left: calc(100% + .5em - .1em);`. Why? What was I doing wrong?

[image]

---

Btw, if any cleaner code can provide that output is very welcome

Answer (score 2):

That's because $half-distance used in

> left: calc(100% + $half-distance - $half-size);
>   is not available inside ***::after*** block.
>   and sass variables should be wrapped inside #{...} for special functions like calc()
>   To fix the above issue you can probably use,

```
span:not(:last-child) {
    $distance: 1em;
    $half-distance: $distance / 2;
    ...,

   &::after {
    $size: .2em;
    $half-size: $size / 2;
    left: calc(100% + #{$half-distance - $half-size});
   }
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgq4ehyb/ Still doesn't work, man, I've tried tweaking around a lot.

Comment: Sorry, you should wrap sass variables inside #{} for specials functions.

Comment: e.g. `right: calc(#{$osize - $fsize});`

Comment: Yes it does solve the problem by putting the sass variable inside an [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation), like described by an article [here](https://tinaja.computer/2017/12/02/sass-interpolation.html). Thank you anyway, any suggestion for getting the code cleaner to get the same output? If no I would probably make yours the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're using `position: absolute` and `display: block` for the pseudo-element? Setting these to `position: relative` and `display: inline-block` should help make positioning them a bit more flexible.

Comment: Nice tip! It works well without `calc()`, as long as the container has enough space to be in one line (which it should always do in my case). Here is the code after applying your tip: https://jsfiddle.net/k4ravhse/.

But if for some reason, I **have to force** the element to be in one line, the answer should be using the old method with the fix of interpolation. https://jsfiddle.net/07cbkuns/